How to get the pendingchanges information using tfvc REST API
I'm attempting to replace the client object model(Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient) Workspace.GetPendingChanges(new[] { new ItemSpec(assetDirectory, RecursionType.Full) }) to the TFVC REST API, but I can't find the corresponding API to query information on pending changes (i.e., to determine if the item is locked).

"Pending changes" is not equivalent to "locked" in TFVC. Which are you actually looking for?

I am afraid that there is no such Rest API can get TFVC Pending Changes information.
In addition to the client object module, we can also use the tf stat command to get the TFVC Pending Changes information.
For example:
tf.exe stat {workspacepath}(e.g. SolutionA\*) /recursive /format:detailed

Result:

It will return TFVC Pending Changes information(inculding lock info).

That's not true. Look at the documentation for the REST API; the TfvcItem response contains an isPendingChange property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#tfvcitem

@DanielMann have you tested this api? It will not show the pending changes info on local workspace. So it will not meet the requirement in question.

The question was unclear in the first place as it referenced wanting to find "locked" files. The question didn't specify whether local or server workspaces are being used or whether exclusive checkout is enabled, so additional clarification is needed before a correct answer can be provided.

@DanielMann The client object shared in the question can get both local and server workspace. And we need to provide workspace path when using the client. This can not be achieved via rest api.  So I add the answer and confirm that there is no rest api can achieve the same feature. And tf command can do the same things.

On the other hand, even when using server workspace, it does not return the  isPendingChange property. The API you shared should be invalid. You can try it before adding the comment.
